# How to originating a Smart Rollup with an installer kernel?

Tags: smart-rollup

I'm attempting to originate a smart rollup with the "TX kernel" at [tezos/kernel](https://gitlab.com/tezos/kernel).  It seems this requires using the tezos_rollup_installer_kernel with the octez-client origination call. I'm looking for instruction on how to use the installer kernel. e.g. How do I provide the subsequent wasm files for the TX kernel?

The steps I have complete so far:

- Build tezos_rollup_isntaller_kernel.wasm
- Hexadecimal encode the .wasm file.
- Originate the rollup passing the hex string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate the `installer` kernel, you can use the `smart-rollup-installer` tool.

### Prerequisites

You will need:

- at least **rust-1.71** installed (you can check with `cargo --version`).
- `$HOME/.cargo/bin` should be available on your `$PATH`.
- `clang`, `v>=11` installed, and set as `CC` environment variable.

### Installing `smart-rollup-installer`

Run the following to install:

```
cargo install tezos-smart-rollup-installer --locked
```

This will place the `smart-rollup-installer` executable at `$HOME/.cargo/bin` by default.

### Creating the installer kernel

Assuming the kernel you'd like to run is called `kernel.wasm`, you can create an installer kernel for it:

```
smart-rollup-installer get-reveal-installer \
    --upgrade-to kernel.wasm \
    --output installer.hex \
    --preimages-dir <preimages-dir>
```

where `<preimages-dir>` is the directory to save the *preimages* of the kernel. The installer will request these through the *reveal data* channel.

And you can now originate the rollup by supplying `installer.hex` to the `octez-client originate smart rollup` command, setting `KERNEL=$(cat installer.hex)`.

### Running a rollup node

To be able to run a rollup node for the rollup, you will need to copy the contents of the `<preimages-dir>` to `${ROLLUP_NODE_DIR}/wasm_2_0_0` - where `${ROLLUP_NODE_DIR}` is the data directory of your rollup node.

Once you've copied these across, you should then be able to run your rollup node, and the installer kernel will automatically upgrade.

For more information on originating the rollup & running a rollup node, see the [rollup docs](https://tezos.gitlab.io/mumbai/smart_rollups.html).

### Using the `octez-smart-rollup-wasm-debugger`

You can also try this out by using the debugger, which may be easier than running a rollup node. To do so you need to use the `.wasm` extension on the `--output` argument:

```
smart-rollup-installer get-reveal-installer \
    --upgrade-to kernel.wasm \
    --output installer.wasm \
    --preimages-dir <preimages-dir>
```

You can then run the installer in the [debugger](https://tezos.gitlab.io/mumbai/smart_rollups.html#testing-your-kernel), using the `--preimage-dir` argument to point to the preimages generated previously:

```
octez-smart-rollup-wasm-debugger installer.wasm --inputs inputs.json --preimage-dir <preimages-dir>
```